# OAuth Dialog has all content positioned off-screen

Tags: bug, api-v2.2, authentication, oauth2

When using `https://stackoverflow.com/oauth/dialog`, the OAuth dialog renders correctly on my normal browser window. Opening it inside a modal however results in an empty window, because `body` has a `min-width` set which shifts the centered box outside of the dialog viewport.

Here's the problem:

[image: OAuth fail]

And here's what it should look like, after I have manually removed the `min-width` and `margin` of the `body`:

[image: OAuth correct]

Is there any way to solve this, is this expected behavior, or is this indeed a bug?

Comment: Confirmed.  But why don't you have scrollbars?

Comment: @BrockAdams I checked it, and I can scroll, macOS/Brave is just hiding the scrollbar when not in use.

Comment: @BrockAdams What is the process for bugs like this? Can I expect a fix in a reasonable time, or should I work around the issue?

Comment: You can expect a fix in ["6 to 8"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/148310) weeks/months/years.  But, seriously, I have no inside track; there is reportedly no one working on the API at SE; and API bug fixes have been few and far between for the last several years.  You can try the contact methods, especially if you work for a company that's paying SE, or if its a major show stopper.  Otherwise, you'd be wise to work around it.

Comment: We have a service that reads from a bunch Oauth APIs and this is the only one with this bizarre behavior. Just remove the min_widith.